# Need help to redirect multiple sites in 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I would like to have help to redirect several of my secondary domain names to my main domain.
At the same time my main domain name must be redirected in "https" and with the "www".

The best I could do for now was with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This works for all but one situation:
when the secondary domain is written following the rules: https + www, it keeps its appearance and does not redirect.

I also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redirection number 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Redirection number 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Redirection number 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example3.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Redirection number 4
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example4.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works on the whole but there must be simpler and shorter no ?

thank you in advance for your help!

### Edit 21/10/22

I think I found with this, tell me if it's OK

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example3.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example3.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess on your main domain to always have `https` with `www`

```
# redirect if not www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Your last edit for redirecting the other domains to your main seems to be ok.